# How to add and assert image upload with image name via playwright?

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright

I have a dialog box with an Upload button named Change and uses `<input id="img-input-link" type="file"  accept="image/*" />` for an image and text input (TextField Mui) to provide name for the image. Below is the automated script I've attempted to perform e2e and I wasn't sure how can I assert both name and image as I'm getting an error

Expected string: "tom.jpg"
Received string: ""

despite my brief attempt. Appreciate your help. Thanks :)

```js
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";
import { login } from "./common";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

test("validate image upload", async ({ page }) => {
  await login(page, "/");

  // navigate to the Images page
  await page.click('text="admin"');
  await page.click('text="Image settings"');
  await page.click('text="Images"');

  const imageName = uuid();

  // start testing
  await page.click('text="Add Image"');
  await page.fill('input[id="Image Name *"]', `${imageName}`);
  await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', "images/tom.jpg");

  await page.click('text="Create"');

   // assert something here
  await expect(page.locator(`text=${imageName}`).first()).toBeVisible();
  await expect(page.locator("img-input-link")).toContainText("tom.jpg");

});
```

Comment: Can you see in the UI that the image was uploaded? If not try executing the test in a non-headless browser and apply wait after `await page.click('text="Create"')`.

Comment: Thanks @AlapanDas, I'll work it out.

Comment: Let me know if it works after applying a wait.

Comment: Hey @AlapanDas, I figured out the issue. The url returned from the api was not awaiting until the url is ready after upload. That's why I wasn't getting an image.